# Two dynamic parts (template)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, templates

I don't know, how to descripe my problem, but I going to try.

I have build my own Template and with one part it is working, but I want to have two parts that are changing, if I click a link.

It is working on my index.php and if I click on the other links, but if I click on news to go back to news(it is my home (index.php)) I will get to a directory explorer.

**a example:**
[image]

**my folder structure:**

[image]

**my htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /inexorablez/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?site=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**my navigation file:**

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="News">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="Teams">Teams</a></li>
    <li><a href="Downloads">Downloads</a></li>
    <li><a href="Partner">Partner</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**my index.php:**

```
if( isset( $_GET['site'] ) ) {

    $site = $_GET['site'];


} else {

    $site = 'News';

}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>inexoarablez</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="unslider/dist/css/unslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="unslider/dist/css/unslider-dots.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<!-- wrapper start -->
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">

        <div id="col-left">

        <!-- logo section start -->
            <div id="logo-section">
                <div id="logo"></div>
                <h1>inexorablez</h1>
            </div>
        <!-- logo section end -->

        </div>


        <div id="col-right">

        <!-- navigation start -->
            <?php require( "includes/navigation.inc.php" ); ?>
        <!-- navigation end -->

        <!-- news start -->
            <div id="news">



                <?php

                    // Navigation

                    switch ( $site ) {

                        case 'News':
                            include( 'news/news.news.php' );
                            break;

                        case 'Teams':
                            include( 'news/teams.news.php' );
                            break;

                        case 'Downloads':
                            include( 'news/downloads.news.php' );
                            break;

                        case 'Partner':
                            include( 'news/partner.news.php' );
                            break;

                        default:
                            include( 'news/news.news.php' );
                            break;

                    }

                ?>

            </div>
        <!-- news end -->

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="main">

        <div id="content">

            <?php

                // Navigation

                switch ( $site ) {

                    case 'News':
                        include( 'sites/news.php' );
                        break;

                    case 'Teams':
                        include( 'sites/teams.php' );
                        break;

                    case 'Downloads':
                        include( 'sites/downloads.php' );
                        break;

                    case 'Partner':
                        include( 'sites/partner.php' );
                        break;

                    default:
                        include( 'sites/news.php' );
                        break;

                }

            ?>

        </div>

    </div>

<!-- footer start -->
    <footer>
        fsdgdsfgfdsg
    </footer>
<!-- footer end -->


</div>
   <!-- wrapper end -->

<!-- scripts -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="unslider/src/js/unslider.js"></script> <!-- but with the right path! -->

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('.my-slider').unslider({
            autoplay: true 
        });

    });
</script>
```

**here a jsfiddle:**
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s17t6bsx/1/)

Sorry for my english, I guess something is wrong, but I don't know really what...

**If I go back to new, I will get this:**
[image]

It is working on my index.php and all other links, but not on the "News" link, if I hit the "News" link I will get the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable directory listings, add this line to your .htaccess file(s)

```
Options -Indexes
```

You can have an .htaccess file in each directory

```
inexorablez/unslider/.htaccess
indexorablez/News/.htaccess
```

and/or at the root

```
indexorablez/.htaccess
```

Comment: Then I will get this error: access denied Error 403, if I hit the link.

It is working on my index.php and all other Links, but not on the "News" link, if I hit the "News" link I will get the folder structure.

Comment: I guess, he is going in the wrong directory! He is going in the "news folder" and not in the "sites folder".

Comment: so, add another .htaccess file to the News folder.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner.. I don't know really, what I have to write inside the second .htaccess? I tought, there is a problem with the switch or the redirect. But why is it working on all other links and only not at the "News" link?